# Excel - listing data from all rows that fall between two dates, while ignoring blank entries

Tags: excel, indexing

I can't get my head around the formula required to return a list of data from all rows in excel that fall between two specific dates.

Sheet1 contains the following data:

```
Date    Region  Reference
01/01/2015  B   4458
01/02/2015  B   6635
01/02/2016  A   3175
01/03/2016  C   2458
01/03/2016  A   2194
01/04/2016  A   3594
01/04/2016  C   
01/05/2016  C   1654
12/05/2016  B   3648
01/06/2016  B   
01/06/2016  B   3296
```

In Sheet2, I specify a start date in cell C2 and an end date in cell C3.

I would like to display a list in sheet2 that gives me a list of all reference numbers in sheet1 that fall  within that date range. I will also however want it to ignore any cells that are blank and do not contain a reference number.

I've tried a few things to get this working, and I think an array formula using an INDEX function is probably the best bet, but I'm struggling to get the date range aspect to work.

Is anybody able to help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you format your data as a table if you haven't already as it makes the index function much easier to read.

The formula below should do what you require.  The * in the if statement is like an "and".  -4 near the end of the formula is the number of rows betwen the source table and the top of the sheet it's on.  The last 1 at the end of the formula is the column that you want to take data from much like you have in a vlookup.  remember to use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it an array formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,SMALL(IF((Table1[Date]>=$C$2)*(Table1[Date]<=$C$3)*(Table1[Reference]<>""),ROW(Table1)-4),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

Formula if you don't want to format as table

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$5:$E$15,SMALL(IF((Sheet2!$C$5:$C$15>=$C$2)*(Sheet2!$C$5:$C$15<=$C$3)*(Sheet2!$E$5:$E$15<>""),ROW(Sheet2!$C$5:$E$15)-4),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

Using the formula

I't not advisible to copy and paste this formula from one cell to another but instead copy the formula text and paste it to avoid parts of the formula changing.

keep an eye on the ROW(1:1) at the end of the formula, it specifies which row from the matching results will be extracted from the data and it should increment when you autofill the formula down the sheet.

[image: Format as Table]

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: Many thanks Gordon. Is there a way of doing this without formatting the data as a table? I appreciate your logic for doing so, however I need to hopefully apply this to a very large set of data that needs to be used in several other ways, and the other users don't want me to amend that data in any way, including amending the formatting...

Comment: You can do it without converting to a table.  replace the fist and last Table1 in the formala with the range you want to index.  Replace Table1[Date] wiith a range for the Date column do the same for the Reference column.  I'll add the new formula to my answer so you can see how it looks.

Comment: Converting to a table doesn't mean that you have to change the format of the data (colous ect.).  It is more about defining the data set so that excel can understand the structure.  If you're not using a table you may need to make your ranges go beyond the data set to avoid having to change your ranges every time new data is added.  If you convert the data to a table then you don't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon. It took me a while to get my head around the solution but it works perfectly!

Comment: I've just tried applying this to a larger spreadsheet containing about 2000 rows of data. It pulls some rows of data through ok, however, it leaves some rows either blank or with a zero in it if there is no data in the source sheet. Preferably I would like to have this display an unbroken list. Is there anything obviously wrong in my adaption of the formula?    =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$V$6000,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$C$3:$C$6000>=Crynodeb!$D$3)*(Sheet1!$C$3:$C$6000<=Crynodeb!$F$3)*(Sheet1!$V$3:$V$6000<>""),ROW(Sheet1!$C$3:$V$6000)-3),ROW(4:4)),22),"")

Comment: if you've taken the formula text from the first row then the ROW(4:4) should be ROW(1:1).  It sounds like it's pulling results where the reference is blank and that may be because the -3 in my formula that describes the position of the 1st source data row doesn't match your data.  You may need to change it to -1 for example if your data is at the top of the sheet with 1 heading row.  If you get that number wrong then all your results will be offset by x rows.  i hope that makes sense.